# IntelliJ IDEA Multiple cursor simultaneously

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I place a cursor at the beginning of each line in a large text file spanning many thousands of lines with as few keystrokes/mouse clicks as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can
1) Search for `\n`
2) Select all occurrences with *Shift + Ctrl + Alt + J (Ctrl + Cmd + G for Mac OS X)*
3) Press right arrow to remove selection